Using WebSockets in MAUI app thrown Exception Error
Using the following code in a .NET Form app. A Websocket connection to a Server is established and the commands are send correctly and received correctly on the server side.
Using the same code in a .NET MAUI app a Exception Error is thrown: 'System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Thanks in advance for some help.

        private async void BtnOn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await SendCommand("O");
        }

        private async void BtnOff_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await SendCommand("F");
        }

        private async Task SendCommand(string command)
        {
            ClientWebSocket socket = new ClientWebSocket();

            try
            {
                await socket.ConnectAsync(new Uri("ws://192.168.0.2:80/command"), CancellationToken.None);

                byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(command);
                await socket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);

                Trace.WriteLine("Incoming message: " + command);

                // Receive response if needed
                var responseBuffer = new byte[1024];
                var response = await socket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(responseBuffer), CancellationToken.None);
                var responseMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBuffer, 0, response.Count);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", $"Error: {ex.Message}", "OK");
            }
            finally
            {
                if (socket.State == WebSocketState.Open || socket.State == WebSocketState.Connecting)
                    await socket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "Closed by the client", CancellationToken.None);

                socket.Dispose();
            }
        }


what is the code/message from the exception object?

This is what i get:
The thread '[Thread Destroyed]' (18688) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '[Thread Destroyed]' (20328) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '[Thread Destroyed]' (15080) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '[Thread Destroyed]' (13036) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '[Thread Destroyed]' (10272) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '[Thread Destroyed]' (4936) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

You can follow the similar issue in MAUI github:Using WebSockets Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll.
